# How to get component to wait for async action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have this form code below:

```
submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { user } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.userName && user.password) {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.register(user));
    } else {
        this.setState({
            error: "Form Incomplete"
        })
    }
    if(this.state.error === "") {
        this.props.history.push("/login");  
    }
}
```

The problem is this.props.dispatch is an async call.  It gets fired when a user successfully fills out the form field.

The problem is it can fail if the username already exists and it will populate the error state.  If this occurs my app keeps going and hits this.props.history and redirects the user even if the form has an error.

How do I basically say "Wait until this.props.dispatch is complete and then check to see if there are any errors.  If not then redirect"?

Comment: instead of waiting for action to complete, better option would be: pass the success or error message from redux store itself, and use `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method and keep checking for error. if any point component recieve the error, show that to user and for success redirect to login.

Comment: Yeah but on init the form will have no error so it will continually redirect the user back to the login page whenever the component is rendered.

Comment: use a bool isError with initial value as false, onSubmit update the value to true if there is any error. in didupdate check the value and show error, at the same time refresh the redux store bool value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `submitForm` as an `async` function like this:

```
submitForm = async (e) => {
```

and then add the `await` keyword before `this.props.dispatch`

```
await this.props.dispatch(userActions.register(user));
```

But since you are using redux, and I am assuming something like redux-promise-middleware, then you should let that handle the success/failure of your async calls.

You mentioned that onInit the form continuously redirects because there is no error set. Can we change the initial error value to `false` and if error is ever `true` then re-direct the user? And then, the only time you would ever set `error` to `true` would be when an actual error came from your call.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you are sending this data to a backend of some sort. Just add a bool to the server response to let your front end know what to do next.

```
submitForm = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const { user } = this.state;
const { dispatch } = this.props;
if (!(  user.password && user.lastName &&user.userName && user.firstName  )) {
    this.props.dispatch(userActions.register(user));
} else {
    this.setState({
        error: "Form Incomplete"
    })
}
if(isValid) {
    this.props.history.push("/login");  
}
}
```